# chrome appcache-internals entry is getting removed

Tags: html5-appcache, chromium-embedded

I have created on web app which supports html5 appcache and I can load that app offline.
I can also see that appcache when I visit URL  `chrome://appcache-internals/`

Now I am using same offline weburl to work on cefclient applicaiton (https://code.google.com/p/chromiumembedded/)

As soon as I try to load that offline url ,exisiting entry from chrome://appcache-internals/ gets removed and my offline web app is not working in cef.

any idea why that is happening. How can I find out why appcache not working with cef.